# Electron MongoDB App

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I am working on using electron (not sure if that matters here) to make a simple html page that puts the logins into a database (mongodb). I am not able to get it to work for some reason. Would appreciate if someone could assist.

dbentry.js below

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "not going to leak my mongo details";
document.ready(function(){
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  db.createCollection("Logins", function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Table created!");
    db.close();
  });
});
  function submitData(){
    var usnfield = document.getElementById("usn").value;
    var pwdfield = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
    document.getElementById('submit').click(function(){
      MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var myobj = { Username: usnfield, Password: pwdfield };
        db.collection("Logins").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("1 record inserted");
          db.close();
        });
      });
    });


  }
});
```

Here is the html page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Database</title>
    <script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'dbentry.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h6>Welcome to my website.</h6>
    <form>
      Username: <input id = "usn" type = "text" name = "username"/>
      Password: <input id = "pwd" type = "password" name = "password"/>
      <input id ="submit" type = "button" name = "submit"/>
      <input id = "retrieve" type = 'button' name = 'retrieve'/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

New to stackoverflow thanks.

Comment: Can you update your question to indicate what part specifically isn't working?  Are you able to get the connection to work, but it's failing on the insert?  Can you check to see if your `err` variables are giving you information about the types of errors you're seeing?